# Loop elimination in R

Tags: r, performance, optimization, vectorization

I am working on a forex-based problem where I have a function that contains loops that loop over the data in the data frame. However, this approach is slower than the same solution coded in VBA by an order of magnitude.

```
  execution_strategy_export <- function(data) {
  
  n <- nrow(data)

  for (i in 1:n) {  
    
    if (is.na(data[i, "outside_business_hours"]) & data[i, "period_one"] <= 0) {
      
      period_one <- data[i, "period_one"]
      today_adjusted_count <- data[i, "today_adjusted_count"]
      IF1 <- data[i,"IF1"]
      today_ref_rate <- data[i, "today_ref_rate"]
      today_adjusted_interval <- data[i, "today_adjusted_interval"]
      today_loss_interval <- data[i, "today_loss_interval"]
      pd_max_period_one <- data[i, "pd_max_period_one"]
      
      prior_period_close_SL <- data[i, "prior_period_close_SL"]
      
      j <- i + 1
      
      while (j <= n) {
        
        # Extract values for the j-th row
        today_open_j <- data[j, "open"]
        today_high_j <- data[j, "high"]
        today_low_j <- data[j, "low"]
        today_close_j <- data[j, "close"]
        
        today_adjusted_count <- max(today_adjusted_count, floor((today_high_j - today_ref_rate) / today_adjusted_interval))
        today_max <- today_ref_rate + (today_adjusted_interval * today_adjusted_count) - today_loss_interval
        
        if (today_open_j < pd_max_period_one || (today_low_j < today_max || today_close_j < today_max)) {
          
          IF1 <- ifelse(today_open_j < pd_max_period_one, min(prior_period_close_SL, pd_max_period_one), today_max)
          
          data[i, "adjusted_count"] <- j - i + 1
          
        }
        
        data[i, "trigger_period"] <- j - i + 1
        
        ifelse(data[i, "trigger_period"] > 1 && (i + data[i, "trigger_period"]) <= n,
               data[i, "trigger_time"] <- data[i + data[i, "trigger_period"] - 1, "time"],
               data[i, "trigger_time"] <- data[i, "time"])
        
        if (IF1 > 0) {
          
          break
          
        }
        
        j <- j + 1
        
      }
      
      data[i, "post_period_two"] <- IF1
      data[i, "result"] <- data[i, "period_one"] + IF1
      data[i, "adjusted_count"] <- today_adjusted_count
      
      if (data[i, "result"] == 0) {
        
        break
        
      }
      
    }
    
  }  

  return(data)
  
}
```

I know R isn't the best with loops so I have tried to avoid using loops in the rest of the code as far as possible and stripped out any calculations that don't need to be done in the loop out of this one but can't seem to find a way to eliminate this specific loop.

I have read that vectorization could be an option but can't seem to wrap my head around how to vectorize the function.

The input data looks like the following (Note there are several variables not used in this function that are used elsewhere in the code):

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(16071, 16071, 16071, 16071, 
16071, 16071, 16071, 16071, 16071, 16071), class = "Date"), 
hhmm = c("07:00:00","07:30:00", "08:00:00", "08:30:00", "09:00:00", "09:30:00", "10:00:00","10:30:00", "11:00:00", "11:30:00"), 
time = c("Wed 01/01/2014 07:00","Wed 01/01/2014 07:30", "Wed 01/01/2014 08:00", "Wed 01/01/2014 08:30","Wed 01/01/2014 09:00", "Wed 01/01/2014 09:30", "Wed 01/01/2014 10:00","Wed 01/01/2014 10:30", "Wed 01/01/2014 11:00", "Wed 01/01/2014 11:30"), 
hour = c(7, 7.3, 8, 8.3, 9, 9.3, 10, 10.3, 11, 11.3), 
open = c(10.44928,10.44917, 10.44915, 10.4505, 10.44757, 10.44941, 10.44819, 10.44842,10.44872, 10.448), 
high = c(10.45217, 10.45143, 10.45159, 10.45168,10.45159, 10.45077, 10.45391, 10.45318, 10.45057, 10.45157), 
low = c(10.44709, 10.44751, 10.4472, 10.44726, 10.44718, 10.4472, 10.44727, 10.44697, 10.44718, 10.44728), 
close = c(10.44946,10.44944, 10.44799, 10.44772, 10.44973, 10.4484, 10.44865,10.44897, 10.44819, 10.44842), 
ref_rate_date = c("Wed 01/01/2014 07:00", "Wed 01/01/2014 07:30", "Wed 01/01/2014 08:00", "Wed 01/01/2014 08:30", "Wed 01/01/2014 09:00", "Wed 01/01/2014 09:30", "Wed 01/01/2014 10:00", "Wed 01/01/2014 10:30", "Wed 01/01/2014 11:00", "Wed 01/01/2014 11:30"), 
ref_rate = c(10.44928, 10.44917, 10.44915, 10.4505, 10.44757, 10.44941, 10.44819, 10.44842, 10.44872, 10.448), 
adjustment_threshold = c(0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001), 
loss_threshold = c(0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003), 
loss_interval = c(0.03134784, 0.03134751, 0.03134745, 0.0313515, 0.03134271, 0.03134823, 0.03134457, 0.03134526, 0.03134616, 0.031344), 
adjustment_interval = c(0.01044928, 0.01044917, 0.01044915, 0.0104505, 0.01044757, 0.01044941, 0.01044819, 0.01044842, 0.01044872, 0.010448), 
outside_business_hours = c("Excl", "Excl", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
stop_loss = c(10.41793216, 10.41782249, 10.41780255, 10.4191485, 10.41622729, 10.41806177, 10.41684543, 10.41707474, 10.41737384, 10.416656), 
max_sl_day_one = c(10.41793216, 10.41782249, 10.41780255, 10.4191485, 10.41622729, 10.41806177, 10.41684543, 10.41707474, 10.41737384, 10.416656), 
period_one = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
result = c(0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
adjusted_count = c(0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
post_period_two = c(0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
trigger_period = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
trigger_time = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
today_period_one_close = c(NA, NA, 10.44799, 10.44772, 10.44973, 10.4484, 10.44865, 10.44897, 10.44819, 10.44842), 
today_loss_interval = c(NA, NA, 0.03134745, 0.0313515, 0.03134271, 0.03134823, 0.03134457, 0.03134526, 0.03134616, 0.031344), 
today_ref_rate = c(NA, NA, 10.44915, 10.4505, 10.44757, 10.44941, 10.44819, 10.44842, 10.44872, 10.448),
today_period_one_high = c(NA, NA, 10.45159, 10.45168, 10.45159,  10.45077, 10.45391, 10.45318, 10.45057, 10.45157), 
today_adjusted_interval = c(NA, NA, 0.01044915, 0.0104505, 0.01044757, 0.01044941, 0.01044819, 0.01044842, 0.01044872, 0.010448), 
today_adjusted_count = c(NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
pd_max_period_one = c(NA, NA, 10.41780255, 10.4191485, 10.41622729, 10.41806177, 10.41684543, 10.41707474, 10.41737384, 10.416656), 
IF1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
input_dbl = c(NA, NA, -0.111013814520676, -0.266015980096604, 0.206746640606374, -0.0966561748463161, 0.0440267644444013, 0.0526395378438767, -0.0507239164222484, 0.0401990811638674), 
close_ref_rate_adjusted_count = c(NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
prior_period_close_SL = c(NA, NA, 10.41780255, 10.4191485, 10.41622729, 10.41806177, 10.41684543,10.41707474, 10.41737384, 10.416656)), row.names = c(NA,10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The output I am looking for for these ten rows of data is as follows:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(16071, 16071, 16071, 16071, 
16071, 16071, 16071, 16071, 16071, 16071), class = "Date"), 
hhmm = c("07:00:00", "07:30:00", "08:00:00", "08:30:00", "09:00:00", "09:30:00", "10:00:00", "10:30:00", "11:00:00", "11:30:00"), 
time = c("Wed 01/01/2014 07:00", "Wed 01/01/2014 07:30", "Wed 01/01/2014 08:00", "Wed 01/01/2014 08:30","Wed 01/01/2014 09:00", "Wed 01/01/2014 09:30", "Wed 01/01/2014 10:00","Wed 01/01/2014 10:30", "Wed 01/01/2014 11:00", "Wed 01/01/2014 11:30"), 
hour = c(7, 7.3, 8, 8.3, 9, 9.3, 10, 10.3, 11, 11.3), 
open = c(10.44928, 10.44917, 10.44915, 10.4505, 10.44757, 10.44941, 10.44819, 10.44842, 10.44872, 10.448), 
high = c(10.45217, 10.45143, 10.45159, 10.45168, 10.45159, 10.45077, 10.45391, 10.45318, 10.45057, 10.45157), 
low = c(10.44709, 10.44751, 10.4472, 10.44726, 10.44718, 10.4472, 10.44727, 10.44697, 10.44718, 10.44728), 
close = c(10.44946, 10.44944, 10.44799, 10.44772, 10.44973, 10.4484, 10.44865, 10.44897, 10.44819, 10.44842), 
ref_rate_date = c("Wed 01/01/2014 07:00", "Wed 01/01/2014 07:30", "Wed 01/01/2014 08:00", "Wed 01/01/2014 08:30", "Wed 01/01/2014 09:00", "Wed 01/01/2014 09:30", "Wed 01/01/2014 10:00", "Wed 01/01/2014 10:30", "Wed 01/01/2014 11:00", "Wed 01/01/2014 11:30"), 
ref_rate = c(10.44928, 10.44917, 10.44915, 10.4505, 10.44757, 10.44941, 10.44819, 10.44842, 10.44872, 10.448), 
adjustment_threshold = c(0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001), 
loss_threshold = c(0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003), 
loss_interval = c(0.03134784, 0.03134751, 0.03134745, 0.0313515, 0.03134271, 0.03134823, 0.03134457, 0.03134526, 0.03134616, 0.031344), 
adjustment_interval = c(0.01044928, 0.01044917, 0.01044915, 0.0104505, 0.01044757, 0.01044941, 0.01044819, 0.01044842, 0.01044872, 0.010448), 
outside_business_hours = c("Excl", "Excl", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
stop_loss = c(10.41793216, 10.41782249, 10.41780255, 10.4191485, 10.41622729, 10.41806177, 10.41684543, 10.41707474, 10.41737384, 10.416656), 
max_sl_day_one = c(10.41793216, 10.41782249, 10.41780255, 10.4191485, 10.41622729, 10.41806177, 10.41684543, 10.41707474, 10.41737384, 10.416656), 
period_one = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
result = c(0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
adjusted_count = c(0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
post_period_two = c(0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
trigger_period = c(NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
trigger_time = c(NA, NA, "Wed 01/01/2014 08:00", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
today_period_one_close = c(NA, NA, 10.44799, 10.44772, 10.44973, 10.4484, 10.44865, 10.44897, 10.44819, 10.44842), 
today_loss_interval = c(NA, NA, 0.03134745, 0.0313515, 0.03134271, 0.03134823, 0.03134457, 0.03134526, 0.03134616, 0.031344), 
today_ref_rate = c(NA, NA, 10.44915, 10.4505, 10.44757, 10.44941, 10.44819, 10.44842, 10.44872, 10.448), 
today_period_one_high = c(NA, NA, 10.45159, 10.45168, 10.45159, 10.45077, 10.45391, 10.45318, 10.45057, 10.45157), 
today_adjusted_interval = c(NA, NA, 0.01044915, 0.0104505, 0.01044757, 0.01044941, 0.01044819, 0.01044842, 0.01044872, 0.010448), 
today_adjusted_count = c(NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
pd_max_period_one = c(NA, NA, 10.41780255, 10.4191485, 10.41622729, 10.41806177, 10.41684543, 10.41707474, 10.41737384, 10.416656), 
IF1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
input_dbl = c(NA, NA, -0.111013814520676, -0.266015980096604, 0.206746640606374, -0.0966561748463161, 0.0440267644444013, 0.0526395378438767, -0.0507239164222484, 0.0401990811638674), 
close_ref_rate_adjusted_count = c(NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
prior_period_close_SL = c(NA, NA, 10.41780255, 10.4191485, 10.41622729, 10.41806177, 10.41684543, 10.41707474, 10.41737384, 10.416656)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your question in current form is a daunting exercise for the reader to imagine what form your data takes and what you want your function to do with it. It looks like you are trying to do some rolling window calculations, where functions from the `data.table` or `zoo` or `slider` packages might be helpful.

Comment: If you want useful help, please provide a bit of sample data (fake is just fine) in the form of code. (This is often easiest using the `dput` function, like `dput(head(data))` and pasting the output into the body of your question. It would also help if you could describe what you want the function to do and provide the expected output. While it sounds like you ultimately want a variety of functions performed, it would also help to narrow the question to one or two of these, as the others are likely to be solved in similar ways.

Comment: There are things in that seem odd, it seems like you are not taking advantage of vectorization.  I don't know why you have loops but as others said, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Just to add, I don't see why you are using loops at all. Why are you creating new names for column vectors? Why are you doing operations row by row? You don't even need *apply for most of this.

Comment: @JonSpring I have added the input and output data so it is easier to understand

Comment: @Elin I know I need to vectorize my code to make it faster but struggling to do it due to the while loop and the break conditions in the code. That is why I ended up on stack overflow to see if someone had advice I could use.

Comment: Okay so can you please provide data and what the results you want are. Also it does not make sense to pull the columns out, just refer to them with either $ or [] notation.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to rewrite your whole function, but I will give you a strategy.

First, start by not putting it into a function, just get it to work.

Second, find the obvious places to fix, maybe starting from the inside and moving out.  For example

```
data$today_adjusted_count <- max(data$today_adjusted_count,
                                  floor((data$high - 
                                   lag(data$today_ref_rate, 1) )/ 
                                    data$today_adjusted_interval),
                                  na.rm = TRUE)
data$today_max <- data$today_ref_rate + 
                 (data$today_adjusted_interval * 
                  data$today_adjusted_count) - 
                   data$today_loss_interval)
```

Can replace a whole lot of code.

Use R functions such as lag().
Don't do the step of pulling everything out into vectors, directly reference the data columns.